# What is considered to be Phuket center?

Tags: thailand, phuket

Which part of Phuket, Thailand, is the city center?
I read many reviews about attractions but it is not clear where is the right place for a vacation. Is it 1 or 2?

[image]

Comment: Why do you need a center to have a good vacation? For example, Krabi center is very distinct from Krabi's good vacation spot, which is Ao Nang. I think it's 2 jugding from where the beach is.

Comment: That depends on what you like. Personally I would prefer to be in a town than at a beach, so it's a matter of opinion.

Comment: Or you can really do both. Why limit yourself to a single location when you can trivially move between a few spots.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The centre of Phuket town is the area you've circled 1. Your area 2 is Patong, which is primarily a tourist resort area - i.e. mostly bars, restaurants etc.

Which, if either, is the 'right' place depends on what you're after - e.g. If you're after loud music, parties etc then you're better off going to Patong, for a quiet beach go to one of the smaller beach villages such as Karon or Kata, or for the historic town stay in Phuket town itself.